# Speed up MsSQL query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a very huge database, 3k+ rows

It takes 4 whole seconds to load the page, with 2 big querys 
How to speed it up?

First:

```
SELECT Description
FROM ComputerIdentity JOIN
     MakeModelIdentity 
     ON ComputerIdentity.MakeModelID = MakeModelIdentity.ID
WHERE MakeModelIdentity.DeviceName='Laptop' AND
      ComputerIdentity.Description LIKE '%uitleen%' AND
      MakeModelIdentity.DeviceName = 'Laptop' AND
      MakeModelIdentity.Model = 'Chromebook' 
ORDER BY ComputerIdentity.ID ASC
```

Second:

```
SELECT Inlognaam,VolledigeNaam FROM PersoneelEnLeerlingen
```

Comment: (1) 3k rows is not huge.  (2) Determine which query is taking the most time and focus on that.  (3) Provide information on whether your tables have indexes.

Comment: Try to find which table field taking time using EXPLAIN and then apply INDEXING to those columns who taking time.

Comment: Also if you can get rid of the first `%` in `ComputerIdentity.Description LIKE '%uitleen%'` it would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3K rows is miniscule, SQL Server Engine doesn't need your help to optimize it. Still here are some suggestions from the book of optimization.
**For First**:

```
SELECT ci.Description
FROM ComputerIdentity ci JOIN
     MakeModelIdentity mmi
     ON ci.MakeModelID = mmi.ID
WHERE mmi.DeviceName = 'Laptop'  AND
      mmi.Model = 'Chromebook' AND
      ci.Description LIKE '%uitleen%' --reordered
ORDER BY ci.ID ASC;
```

1. Make sure your IDs are integer
2. Create clustered indexes on ComputerIdentity.MakeModelID and MakeModelIdentity.ID, in case you can make them primary key, that would be the best. Create a non-clustered index on Description, Device Name and Model
3. If you can remove '%' operator try to that. '%' operator in front is very costly, by which I mean '%uitleen%' is slower than 'uitleen%'. If you can remove like operator, that would be great.

**For Second:** Create non-clustered indexes on the columns you are selecting, which doesn't have a clustered index

Comment: I can't remove the % operator, because the name of the devices are ICT Uitleen *** - but I can try ICT Uitleen %

Comment: Please do that, as If it knows the alphabet with which the string starts, it rules out all other strings. Imagine the gain in speed, for example, searching words starting with u, instead of searching all the words.

Answer (score 0):

For this query (which I've "simplified" using table aliases and removing the redundant `WHERE` condition):

```
SELECT ci.Description
FROM ComputerIdentity ci JOIN
     MakeModelIdentity mmi
     ON ci.MakeModelID = mmi.ID
WHERE mmi.DeviceName = 'Laptop' AND
      ci.Description LIKE '%uitleen%' AND
      mmi.Model = 'Chromebook' 
ORDER BY ci.ID ASC;
```

You can speed the query with indexes on `MakeModelIdentity(DeviceName, Model, ID)` and `ComputerIdentity(MakeModelID, Description, ID)`.

The second query is really simple and the speed only depends on the size of the data.

Comment: can you please help me understand how you chose the indexes?